# How to extract lat long from google earth city database

Tags: geolocation, google-earth

Is it possible to extract google earth city database? What do i have to do to get it? Any reference will be appreciated.

PS: I haven't done any scripting related to google earth before.

Thanks!

Comment: Before you start that, you might want to have a look at the Google Earth Terms of Service, especially sections 2.b/c/d/f, which prohibit extracting the data/content provided by Google. 
https://maps.google.com/help/terms_maps.html
There are other sources of data for things like cities available out there with licenses that allow various uses, I suggest you look for some of those.

Comment: Thanks for your information @ChristiaanAdams